# fancybox not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I followed the code in this jsfiddle and wrote everything in a single html file.
What is missing as it is not working as shown in jsfiddle?
http://jsfiddle.net/kevin11189/uZCC6/1270/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-thumbs hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

    <a class="fancybox-thumbs hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

</body>
<script language="JavaScript">

    $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',

        closeBtn  : true,
        arrows    : false,
        nextClick : true,                

        helpers : {
            thumbs : {
                width  : 50,
                height : 50
            }
        }
    });

</script>
</html>
```

**Total newbie here!

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is to be new to Fiddle, from what I can see...

Because you would have seen the external ressources loaded.
Add this in the `<head>` of your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css">
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
```

And see how it is working great when all libs are loaded.
;)

**EDIT**
mmm...
Also add jQuery on top of that...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why it doesn't show in Fiddle externals...
But it's needed.

**2nd EDIT**
It looks like it is working better with jQuery 2.2.4 instead of jQuery 3.1.1...
The thumbnails were not showing...

So add this instead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
```